# Which event of  LookUpEdit  control  Should use for getting result as  google address bar?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm using `DevExpress LookUpEdit control` in my application. I want to set the datasource property of control when user types any character in the LookUpEdit control. which event should i use for this operation?.
I want the result as `google address bar` working . Can anybody help me?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `TextChanged`-Event what you are looking for?

You might also have a look at the Events in the [Documentation at DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEditClassEventsTopic)

Edit:
I think [I found the answer](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/D1132.aspx)

Comment: I'd used the TextChanged-Event of LookUpEdit. But the problem with the event that i faced is as i type "a" character the top most value is focused in the text area of LookUpEdit. so the TextChanged-Event occurs two times and in the second time it changes the text value to blank even if it contains a character.I don't want this working of LookUpEdit Control. How to handle this?

Comment: @Richa: I think I found the answer. See the new link in my answer above.